Sublime Text: PHP Companion namespace not imported correctly
I have Sublime Text 4 with PHP Companion.
I have the following standard key bindings to automatically import namespaces
{ "keys": ["f9"], "command": "expand_fqcn" }, /* add namespace to called method */
{ "keys": ["f10"], "command": "find_use" },   /* add 'use namespace\method;' to top of file  */

Both work as expected except when the class is in the root namespace (namespace is empty).
For instance I have a class system with no namespace in there that has the static method doSystemStuff().
If I want to call that method in another file and put the cursor on the method name and press F9 I get \system\system::doSystemStuff() instead of the expected \system::doSystemStuff(). F10 produces the same doubling.
Since these are my most used classes (hence the shortest path) getting them wrong every time is rather irritating. And since 99% of my classes do have a namespace, I need the use every time.
Also native PHP classes are not supported: so no use DateTime; after F10.
I have no clue how to solve this, Google doesn't help. Does anyone have an idea? I tried the empty namespace (by using namespace { class system {...} }) but PHP Companion doesn't handle bracketed namespaces (or rather, produces garbage).
